# Class Type Required but C Found

Tags: scala

I have looked over the many questions already asked about this, but none of them worked or seemed to fit with the issue I am having.

This is my abstract class:

```
abstract class GuiPowerBase[C <: Container](tile: TileBankBase, player: InventoryPlayer, width: Int, height: Int, name: String)
                                    extends GuiBase[C](new C(player, tile), width, height, name) {
```

This is GuiBase class:

```
abstract class GuiBase[T <: Container](val inventory : T, width : Int, height: Int, name : String)
    extends GuiContainer(inventory) with INEIGuiHandler {
```

and this is one of what will be calling GuiPowerBase:

```
class GuiSolidsBank(player: InventoryPlayer, tileEntity: TileBankSolids)
    extends GuiPowerBase[ContainerSolidsBank](tileEntity, player, 175, 165, "inventory.solidspower.title") {
```

With everything I have looked at, it seems I need a ClassTag, or maybe a Manifest, but everything I have tried doesn't seem to work. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why you see this error is in the following line:

```
extends GuiBase[C](new C(player, tile), width, height, name)
```

In Scala, as well as in Java, type variables are erased during execution, so in runtime there's no info about the `C` type variable, unless you are not using reflection to get this info into runtime. Though it's possible to go this way, i personally dislike it in favor of type class approach, which gives us ad-hoc polimorphism. Here's the approach with type class:

```
trait ContainerBuilder[C <: Container] {
  def build(title: TileBankBase, player: InventoryPlayer): C
}

object ContainerBuilder {
  def apply[C <: Container: ContainerBuilder]: ContainerBuilder[C] = implicitly[ContainerBuilder[C]]

  implicit val containerSolidsBank: ContainerBuilder[ContainerSolidsBank] = {
    new ContainerBuilder[ContainerSolidsBank] {
      def build(title: TileBankBase, player: InventoryPlayer): ContainerSolidsBank = ???
    }
  }
}

abstract class GuiPowerBase[C <: Container: ContainerBuilder](tile: TileBankBase, player: InventoryPlayer, width: Int, height: Int, name: String)
  extends GuiBase[C](ContainerBuilder[C].build(player, tile), width, height, name)
```

Using this approach can help you avoid reflection. Of course it's too specific for your given case, but no one stops you from making it more general, e.g with dependant types.

Comment: Thank you VERY much. This has taken me hours to get working!